# Is it possible to check an Idle Application from another application?

Tags: c#

I have several programs that are already released. I want to create new program to read the released running programs - wheather they are idle or not for about 5 minutes. If they are in the idle condition, I want to terminate them.

IDLE means the user not use mouse and keyboard or no process in that program.

As an example, these are my several released programs:

- pgrA.exe - Running - Idle 3 Minutes
- pgrB.exe - Stopped
- pgrC.exe - Running - Idle 7 Minutes
- pgrD.exe - Running - not Idle
- pgrE.exe - Running - Idle 11 Minutes

My program to terminate idle programs (on single PC):

- IdleReader.exe (will terminate pgrC.exe and pgrE.exe)

that all running in 1 PC.

this some codes of the new program to terminate idle Program:

```
private void refresh_PrgList()
    {

        using (var con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionStr"]))
        using (var cmd = con.CreateCommand())
        {
            con.Open();
            cmd.CommandText = "select ProgramID, ProgramName from MKTPrograms";
            var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            var yy = false;
            dgvPrgList.Rows.Clear();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                yy = false;
                foreach (var xx in Process.GetProcesses())
                    if (xx.ProcessName.Replace(".exe", string.Empty).ToUpper() == reader[0].ToString().Replace(" ", string.Empty).ToUpper())
                    {
                        //----- I want to Detect the Idle Program here -----//

                        //--------------------------------------------------//
                        dgvPrgList.Rows.Add(new object[] { reader[0].ToString(), reader[0].ToString(), "Running", xx.StartTime, System.DateTime.Now - xx.StartTime });
                        yy = true;
                    }
                if (yy == false)
                    dgvPrgList.Rows.Add(new object[] { reader[0].ToString(), reader[1].ToString(), "Stopped", "" });
            }

            for (int x = 1 ; x < dgvPrgList.Columns.Count ; x++ )
            {
                dgvPrgList.Columns[x-1].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.DisplayedCells;
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks,

Comment: Yes it is. You could use socket communication or named pipes or create files and write to files to get what you want.

Comment: This seems to be a heavily opinionen based question, and since there is no code or not even a start, i would doubt that it belongs here...

Comment: Arief, You should first try to do "something" and put the code here what You've tried. For example, try to obtain some list of running programs. Try to get their state. Try to terminate the program. Then ask, what is the issue and why is it not working.

Comment: Yes it definitely is. The solution/approach depends on the technology you are already using. Are you using WCF, WebSockets, etc.?

Comment: What exactly is "idle"? That will depend on the specific application. So you will need a way to ask the application whether it considers itself to be idle and gracefully shut down if so (any changes to save?). Why not build it into the apps themselves to exit when idle, maybe even with a countdown?

Comment: There may be many opinions to implement this , try your own and then tell us what code you have tried, for exam you can get CPU percentage of an app for a while and etc...

Comment: Sorry for the confusing question, that i revised the question.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, there are tons of ways to do that.

Look at the processing time (UserProcessorTime,TotalProcessorTime), store it and compare it; you'd get a good feeling about "idle" after some time.

Then just call Kill on the System.Diagnostics.Process class to terminate it.

In .net one can do:

```
var processName= "yourApp";
if (Process.GetProcessesByName(processName) == null)
    Assert.Inconclusive("Skipped: {processName} is not running");
```

The above code is a unit test, and it can be used to get a specific process, you can find the name you are looking for in your resource monitor:

[image: Resource Monitor]

To see if an application is installed one would simulate the call to start that application, you'd do that like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Determines whether the specified application executable is installed.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="name">The command line name.</param>
/// <returns><c>true</c> if the specified name is installed; otherwise, <c>false</c>.</returns>
public static bool IsInstalled(string name)
{
    using (var key = Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey($"{name}\\shell\\open\\command"))
        return key != null;
}
```

One can check if an application is having the right state by looking at the main window. you do this by getting the process as shown before
what I do to see if the application has started but the user is still at his login is:

```
if (MyAppProcess.MainWindowTitle.Contains("Login"))
    return true;
```

I use:

```
if (!TCP.IsListing(login.ServerName, login.Port))
                    Assert.Inconclusive($"Skipped: TWS not accepting connection port {login.Port}");
```

To see if a method is accepting connections without actually creating a connection, no all applications like it when you just open a socket port, some crash, some corrupt.

The code that does that is listed below, only works locally, you can't do this remote. I use the host as my servers have more than 1 IP and failing to listen will cause my application to fire up a fallback instance and update the DNS server. Easy to create an application failover cluster without having to have enterprise licenses for all your multi-socket multi-core servers ;-)

```
public static bool IsListing(string hostUri, int portNumber, int millisecondTimeOut=500)
{
    try
    {
        var info = new ProcessStartInfo() {
            Arguments = "-a -p TCP",
            CreateNoWindow=false,
            FileName="netstat",
            WindowStyle= ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true
        };
        using (var p = Process.Start(info))
        using (StreamReader reader = p.StandardOutput)
        {
            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                var line = reader.ReadLine();
                if (line.Contains($":{portNumber}"))
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }

        }
        return false;

    }
    catch (SocketException)
    {
        return false;
    }

}
```

You can see if a host (remote or local) can be reached using a ping. You can do that using:

```
public static async Task<bool> IsOnline(string hostUri)
{
    try
    {
        object token = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        using (var p = new Ping())
        {
            var result= await p.SendPingAsync(hostNameOrAddress: hostUri, timeout: 1000);
            return result.Status == IPStatus.Success;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {                
        return false;
    }
}
```